# How to execute socket.io endpoints sychronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous, socket.io

My application is using *socket.io*, from what I gather, *socket.io* executes asynchronously. Most of the time this is not a problem, however there is a particular case where 2 users in my app may call the same socket endpoint at the same time, and this causes issues.

What I would rather have is for each socket endpoint to wait until the one before it finishes executing, before it gets executed. If they run asynchronously, I get unexpected results.

On the server I have the following...

```
// Establish a connection with a WebSocket.
io.on("connection", socket => {

  socket.on("add_song", async (data) => {
    PlaylistHandler.add_song(io, socket, data);      
  });

...
...
```

`add_song` gets called at the same time by two different `io` connections (2 different users). I don't want the function `PlaylistHandler.add_song` to run in parallel for each so I tried using *async/await*...

```
await PlaylistHandler.add_song(io, socket, data);
```

That didn't solve anything because I suspect it is because there are two different `io` connections making the call.

Is there any way to make the socket call itself run sequentially rather than in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` doesn't block the event loop, so it indeed doesn't matter here. Both `await PlaylistHandler.add_song` will get executed in their respective `io.on` listeners in parallel.

Your best/easiest shot is to set a variable `calculating = true` at the beginning of your `add_song`, and to postpone any `add_song` if we are already doing one.

Hope this snippet will inspire you into achieving a workable solution:

```
let calculating = false;

function add_song(io, socket, data){
    if(calculating){
        setTimeout(function(){
            add_song(io, socket, data)
        }, 500); //depends on how often you want to check, reduce/increase timeout depending on how time-sensitive checking should be       
        return;
    }
    calculating = true;

    //Do all your usual add_song processing

    //After final operation of add_song
    calculating = false;
}
```